# "Lithos pro regular" font is not working in Firefox but works in Chrome and IE

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

I have basic Html page. I want the fonts to use "Lithos Pro Regular" as their font-family but the font is applying well in IE 8 ,9 and Chrome but not applying in Firefox.

```
   <style>.resetsavecontainer
            {
width:116px;
height:92px;
float:left;
background:url(../assets/reset,save.png) no-repeat;
margin:42px 0px 0px 8px;    
     }
    .resetsavecontainer span
      {
font: 13px "Lithos Pro Regular";
color:#FFF; 
display:inline-block;
margin: 11px 0px 0px 12px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
 </style>
  <body>
           <div class="resetsavecontainer">
                        <span>RESET</span>
                        <span>SAVE</span>
                </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Have you embed the font via @font-face?

Comment: no i'm not adding a custom font. so i have not embedded @font-face.

Comment: font is applying like defaults predefined fonts in the system.
There are no issues in CHROME and IE8 9. Only in FIREFOX.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7DV7P/ 
@all
Check the link in different browsers. fonts are not applying in firefox

Comment: I just checked it but I got different result. Firefox display it properly but Chrome didn't. Rather than relying on system fonts, why not just convert the font into webfont? You can use [webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to convert Lithos into webfont. I am sure it will display correctly on any browsers even IE7.

Answer (score 1):

As font-face is compatible with all browsers, just try this way:

```
@font-face
{
  font-family: yourfont;
  src: url(path_of_font );
}

div
{
  font-family:yourfont;
}
```

Comment: its a system font..  Whats the path i should give.. should i manually download it ?

Comment: refer to this site....It may useful to you http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/10/30/how-to-use-css-font-face/

Comment: In the URL just give the name of your font and try it.